# ¿Como puedo actualizar la imagen de un ImageButton automaticamente en kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

La idea es que dentro de mi carpeta files del proyecto android se irán creando imágenes que coincidirán en nombre con un ImageButton, y el siguiente codigo deberia leer las imagenes de la carpeta y asignarlas al ImageButton de su mismo nombre:

```
    val directoryEdex = File(context.filesDir, "edex")
        val listOfImages = directoryEdex.listFiles()
        if (listOfImages != null) {
            for (image in listOfImages) {
                val imageName = image.nameWithoutExtension
                val imageButtonId = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "id", packageName)
                if (imageButtonId != 0) {
                    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(imageButtonId)
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.absolutePath)
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    imageButton.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
                    imageButton.adjustViewBounds = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Creo que el problema del codigo es que no llega a detectar la carpeta o los archivos dentro y por ello no asigna las imágenes

Comment: El uso de resources.getIdentifier() es para imágenes que se encuentran en tu proyecto, no para imágenes que descargas a disco, revisa mi respuesta , ahí te propongo una mejor solución.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que tratas de realizar solo puede cargar imágenes que se encuentran en tu proyecto, es decir que se encuentran dentro del directorio `/drawable`,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

además, en este caso para cargar imágenes estás definiendo que el recurso se encuentra en el directorio "id", lo cual es incorrecto:

```
val imageButtonId = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "id", packageName)
```

"id" se usa para vistas.

el directorio de donde debes obtener las imágenes debe ser "drawable":

```
val imageButtonId = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", packageName)
```

---

**Cargar imagen de disco a ImageButton.**

La solución que te recomiendo es obtener el archivo que guardaste en disco, debes definir el directorio y su nombre de imagen, posteriormente cargar en tu `ImageButton`:

```
val directoryEdex = File(context.filesDir, "edex")
val listOfImages = directoryEdex.listFiles()
var file = null
    if (listOfImages != null) {
        for (image in listOfImages) {
         //*Obtiene imagen.
         file = File(requireContext().filesDir, "/edex/$image")
         val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.absolutePath)
         //*Carga imagen en ImageButton
         imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
```